# How to call an object to a if statement

Tags: android-studio, class, object, methods, constructor

Ive created a class called 'User' below and now in my main Activity I am trying to call the objects in the class to check to see if the input the user has entered is correct and matches the user objects, if it is correct then I want it to move to the next screen. But at the moment when i open the app and put in user1 correct details and click the login button nothing happens. Is there something wrong in my code? No errors are coming up to help me detect what is wrong. Here is my code below for my User class and main activity.

```
public class User {

// Instance variables
static String userName;
static String password;
static String favColor;


// User constructor
public User(String initUserName, String initPassword, String initFavColor) {
    userName = initUserName;
    password = initPassword;
    favColor = initFavColor;

}
public String getUserName(){
    return userName;
}

public String getPassword(){
    return password;
}

public String getFavColor(){
    return favColor;
}
```

}

```
    logInBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void  onClick(View view) {

            User user1 = new User("Jason", "Sword", "Red");
            User user2 = new User("Billy", "Dinosaur", "Blue");
            User user3 = new User("Zack", "Elephant", "Black");
            User user4 = new User("Trini", "Tiger", "Yellow");
            User user5 = new User("Kimberly", "Bird", "Pink");

            String userET = userEditText.getText().toString();
            String userPassword = passwordEditText.getText().toString();

            if(userET.equals(user1.getUserName() + userPassword.equals(user1.getPassword()))){

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(i);

            } else if(userET.equals(user2.getUserName() + userPassword.equals(user2.getPassword()))){

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(i);

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect details, Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In your if statement you compare userET with (user2.getUserName() + "True" or "False")

Check this and do the same for the others

```
if(userET.equals(user1.getUserName()) && userPassword.equals(user1.getPassword()))
```

And the reason for why you are not displaying any Toast is because you forget .show()

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect details, Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I recommend you to use Log.d for a better debugging experience :)

Comment: Thats awesome thank you so much! But now for some reason even when i type in the correct details of the username and password it is saying the details are incorrect. Do you know why this would be?

Comment: You should really do the debug by yourself using Log, try to print the input from the forms and then the returned value from string comparaison. It would be easier for us if you can show the output.